# addressing and setting 2 datepicker fields on WordPress with Ninja Forms

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, pikaday, ninja-forms

On WordPress is use Ninja Forms. i have a page with multiple Date Fields in the same Form ( date of arrival and date of departure). I need to change the Value of both Date fields.

the following example script works (i can add jQuery to the page by a WP plugin), but is changing the value of both fields:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
new(Marionette.Object.extend( {
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'pikaday' ), 'init', this.modifyDatepicker );
    },
    modifyDatepicker: function( dateObject, fieldModel ) {
        dateObject.pikaday.setDate( '04/11/2016' );
    }
}));
});
</script>
```

i don't know how to address the 2 fields separately. The 2 fields created by Ninja Forms look like this (they differ only by the ID):

```
<div class="nf-field-element">
<div class="pikaday__container"><input id="nf-field-66" name="nf-field-66" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element datepicker" value="11/04/2016" type="hidden">
<input class="pikaday__display pikaday__display--pikaday ninja-forms-field nf-element datepicker" placeholder="" type="text">
</div></div>
```

Any idea how to adjust the jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to fix the exact same problem for a client. Although I did not fix it via jQuery my solution might help you - or anyone else with a similar problem:

I had to pre-populate my datepickers with values defined in query-strings and did it the following way:

1. Add a filter that hooks into 'ninja_forms_render_default_value'
2. Filter for 'date' field type
3. Check for a date field with a given key
4. Check if query-string is set

To achieve the same you can just copy this into your functions.php:

```
    add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'my_change_nf_default_value', 10, 3 );

    function my_change_nf_default_value( $default_value, $field_type, $field_settings ) {

        if ('date' == $field_type ) {

            if ('date_from_query_string' == $field_settings['key']) {
                if (!empty( get_query_var('date_from') )) {
                    return get_query_var('date_from');
                }
            }

            if ('date_from_query_string' == $field_settings['key']) {
                if (!empty( get_query_var('date_to') )) {
                    return get_query_var('date_to');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```